# Why enforcing order onto Julia matrix vector multiplications has speed up?

Tags: julia

I've tried the following.

```
a = randn(100,100);
b = randn(100,100);
c = randn(100,1);

@time a*b*c
@time a*(b*c)
```

## Results

```
julia> @time a*b*c;
  0.000591 seconds (7 allocations: 79.234 KiB)

julia> @time a*(b*c);
  0.000101 seconds (6 allocations: 1.906 KiB)
```

Results are quite consistent with the above.  While it does make intuitive sense why the the second one is better (A matrix-vector multiplication twice instead of a large matrix-matrix multiplication).

I was wondering, shouldn't Julia have optimized this knowing that the dimensions of the matrices and it could've reordered the operation to have optimized it?  Or am I just being too lazy to wish for that or are there other technical issues that I don't see.

So, this is what I get when I use `dump()` on `(a*b*c)`

```
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array{Any}((4,))
    1: Symbol *
    2: Array{Float64}((100, 100)) [0.290788 -0.0601455 … -0.408164 1.16261; -0.539274 -1.56979 … 2.56233 0.806247; … ; 1.30981 -1.31929 … 1.38655 -1.89169; -1.58483 0.318804 … -0.0500151 2.13105]
    3: Array{Float64}((100, 100)) [-0.464882 1.60371 … -0.390234 0.605401; -1.06837 0.296049 … 0.759708 0.0124688; … ; -0.149613 -1.38653 … 0.284494 1.47524; 0.34351 0.420449 … 0.544973 1.85736]
    4: Array{Float64}((100, 1)) [1.64066; 0.593296; … ; 0.908361; 0.486164]
  typ: Any
```

`dump(a*(b*c))`

```
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array{Any}((3,))
    1: Symbol *
    2: Array{Float64}((100, 100)) [0.290788 -0.0601455 … -0.408164 1.16261; -0.539274 -1.56979 … 2.56233 0.806247; … ; 1.30981 -1.31929 … 1.38655 -1.89169; -1.58483 0.318804 … -0.0500151 2.13105]
    3: Expr
      head: Symbol call
      args: Array{Any}((3,))
        1: Symbol *
        2: Array{Float64}((100, 100)) [-0.464882 1.60371 … -0.390234 0.605401; -1.06837 0.296049 … 0.759708 0.0124688; … ; -0.149613 -1.38653 … 0.284494 1.47524; 0.34351 0.420449 … 0.544973 1.85736]
        3: Array{Float64}((100, 1)) [1.64066; 0.593296; … ; 0.908361; 0.486164]
      typ: Any
  typ: Any
```

So, is there an issue trying to optimize on this assuming operators are associative?  Does it become very complex or intractable otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: This whole answer assumes that `*` is a binary operator in Julia. **This is incorrect** and as such the OP question is perfectly valid. See https://discourse.julialang.org/t/is-there-any-way-to-make-custom-binary-infix-operators-right-associative/3202/5 for some discussion (specifically mentioning that `*` is parsed as n-arry, [which can be seen here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/0d7248e2ff65bd6886ba3f003bf5aeab929edab5/base/docs/helpdb/Base.jl#L1917-L1923)). I will leave the original answer below.

Matrix-matrix multiplication takes `n^3` steps (for smallish matrices). Matrix-vector multiplication takes `n^2` steps.

`a*b*c` is the same as `(a*b)*c` which takes a total of `n^3+n^2` operations, while `a*(b*c)` takes `2*n^2` operations because it contains only matrix-vector multiplications.

If you want something to automatically optimize your matrix algebra expression, you can try a library like https://github.com/Jutho/TensorOperations.jl (the first hit on google for that type of question). Another option mentioned in the comments is https://github.com/AustinPrivett/MatrixChainMultiply.jl

As to why Julia does not do this automatically: That would have to be part of the parser (precedence of operators), however you do not want the parser to be able to peek inside the runtime in order to learn what the object is. On the other hand, this is certainly achievable with a macro applied before compilation as done by the aforementioned packages. Maybe it is also feasible if you use some compile-time type information, however this will be a rather ugly special-case for only a couple of types in the otherwise elegant multiple-dispatch mechanism of Julia.

Comment: This package: https://github.com/AustinPrivett/MatrixChainMultiply.jl probably addresses the question more directly.

Comment: Krastanov: Oh, I get why one is faster than the other.  However, I'm not sure why Julia doesn't exploit the fact that multiplication is an associative operator during compilation and why we need to order them by hand (or by via modules pointed out by  @DNF.  Of course, I'm being way too lazy here and can probably figure out this for most of the algorithms I will implement and was just curious.

Comment: @Akaberto, I see now. The gist of it is that what you want will need to be part of the parser (precedence of operators), however you do not want the parser to be able to peek inside the runtime in order to learn what the object is. On the other hand, this is certainly achievable with a macro applied before compilation as done by the aforementioned packages.

Comment: @Krastanov: Ah, perhaps not the parser but surely, this could've been part of the optimizer, right?  I thought  Julia's JIT would've seen this and optimized it.  That's why I was surprised about this.

Comment: I still think this would be rather invasive and agains the principle of "least surprise". "*" is associative only for certain types and it is inherently a binary operator. What you are suggesting would be a fragile special case works only on certain types and completely ruins the intuition one has about how multiple dispatch is supposed to work. The only reasonable solution I can think of that does not require a macro is to create a multiplication function with a variable number of arguments (instead of the binary *), but at that point the macro seems cleaner.

Comment: @Akaberto, this might be a useful resource that shows some errors in my original answer https://discourse.julialang.org/t/is-there-any-way-to-make-custom-binary-infix-operators-right-associative/3202/5